# Is there a way to find the number with the highest probability of being the next one in a user input list?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

So the user inputs a list of n numbers in one string (not more than 1000), and the program finds and outputs the number with the highest probability of occuring next. I'm somewhat of a beginner and am stuck on counting the prbability, Python won't let me convert both he list element and the method I'm using to ints:

```
n = [int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())]
for i in n:
    P = collections.Counter([i]) / len(n)
    print(P)  # The program is supposed to determine the highest possibility and print the respective number afterwards
```

Comment: How are you supposed to compute the probability? Is this just taking into account the pairwise frequencies? What would be the expected number for `1213141516171`?

Comment: This would require some significant assumptions.  The answers would be quite different depending on whether the data are independent or serially correlated as with an [ARMA model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive–moving-average_model).

Comment: _Python won't let me ..._ We have no idea what this means.  Please explain what the program **actually does**!  If you get an error, post it.  If you get unexpected results, tell us.

Comment: Lots of assumptions for the question. One thing to consider (if you actually need to predict) is conditional independence. You could do a markov assumption P(next|prev) and just condition on the most recently seen. This would give you an NxN table where N is the range of numbers that can be produced. Taking **just** the most frequent could lead to some very misleading calculations...

Comment: @Chrispresso ARMA models would be more general than Markovian models, they allow that the next value could be conditionally dependent on more than one historical value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
import collections

n = [int(input()) for _ in range(5)]
p = collections.Counter(n)
for i, freq in p.items():
    print(f"{i}: {freq / len(n)}")
```

The parameter to `collections.Counter` should be your list; you can then iterate over `Counter` as a dict where the keys are the items in the list (the numbers entered by the user) and the values are the number of times each item appeared.  Dividing the count by the total length of the list tells you the percentage of the time each item appeared.

```
1
2
3
2
2
1: 0.2
2: 0.6
3: 0.2
```

If you want to just get the single most frequently appearing number, take the `max` like this:

```
print(f"Most frequent: {max(p, key=p.get)}")
```

Comment: thank you, I will try to adapt your code to better fit the requirements. The problem was counting the elemnts